# Question about the generated Hibernate Queries in 3 situation

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I want to learn relations among tables and i met a question about data persistance.

I created 2 entities, User and Dog. Suppose it's a single-direction many-to-one relation, one user can have many dogs, one dog can only have one user.

In DogEntity Class:

```
    @ManyToOne                   
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private UserEntity user;
```

And no private field in UserEntity class.

When I test like below:

```
    @Test
    public void saveManyFirst(){
        UserEntity user1 = new UserEntity("user2@qq.com", "123qwe",
                "zhangsan2",null,
                null,null,
                null);
        DogEntity dog1 = new DogEntity("Sakura","Akita",null,user1);
        DogEntity dog2 = new DogEntity("Sakura2","Akita2",null,user1);

        dogDao.save(dog1);
        dogDao.save(dog2);
        userDao.save(user1);
    }
```

It's reasonable to get an error as "object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing".

Then I added @Transactional as below:

```
    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void saveManyFirst(){
        UserEntity user1 = new UserEntity("user2@qq.com", "123qwe",
                "zhangsan2",null,
                null,null,
                null);
        DogEntity dog1 = new DogEntity("Sakura","Akita",null,user1);
        DogEntity dog2 = new DogEntity("Sakura2","Akita2",null,user1);

        dogDao.save(dog1);
        dogDao.save(dog2);
        userDao.save(user1);
    }
```

I got three Inserts, and [table of dog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RvIg.png),[table of user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g85NT.png).
The FKs in table of Dog are null.

Then I added @Rollback(false)  (the defalut value is true).

```
    @Test
    @Transactional
    @Rollback(false)
    public void saveManyFirst(){
        UserEntity user1 = new UserEntity("user2@qq.com", "123qwe",
                "zhangsan2",null,
                null,null,
                null);
        DogEntity dog1 = new DogEntity("Sakura","Akita",null,user1);
        DogEntity dog2 = new DogEntity("Sakura2","Akita2",null,user1);

        dogDao.save(dog1);
        dogDao.save(dog2);
        userDao.save(user1);
    }
```

I got 3 Inserts and 2 more updates, and the FKs in table of Dog are updated as wished.
[table of dog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkaaU.png)

Of course I know I should better save the one who has the FK first, but I'm learning Spring Data Jpa, I really want to know why this happend. Could you please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Take a tour and get your first badge-https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

When you have one transaction spanning over all operations, because at the end of the trasaction, it sees that Dog references a User which is already what JPA calls *managed*.

When you have no transaction, Spring-Data JPA create a transaction per call i.e. each call to save. So you have 3 transactions. Now the first transaction when it is about to commit tries to flush and sees that the dog does not have a *managed* User reference but a transient one, which is why you get the error.

Note that a flush can be triggered when loading/querying as well, so it's important that you either use proper cascades on your associations or make sure the flushing happens in the appropriate order.